# Show html color from a string

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, backend

I have a string, in a variable "prod.de.description", that is a description of an object, like that:

```
"<p><strong>Test</strong></p><p><strong><span style="background-color: #ed7e32;">Test2</span></strong></p>"
```

When I use innerhtml, it's show only the strong but not the background color. Here is the html code and the result:

```
 <div class="col-10" style="padding-left:0; font-size:0.9rem">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 text-right">
        <label class="modal-tag">DESCRIPTION</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <p [innerHTML]="prod.de.description"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That's what I get since now:

[image: The result of my code]

Why I don't get the background color under Test2 but only the strong?
I'm newbie of HTML. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try putting single quotation inside double quotations. Or the vice versa. Like `"<p><strong>Test</strong></p><p><strong><span style='background-color: #ed7e32;'>Test2</span></strong></p>"
`

Comment: you have to take care of the literal double quotes in some way, either replace double quotes in the string with single quotes or wrap the string in single quotes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `innerHTML` directive of framework and it sanitises the content before putting into your `dom`. It will remove styles tag and script things as security issue. Outsiders can attack with their on content. To prevent that, framework does this thing.

However, framework also gives way to escape this when you know that you are putting content from `trusted sources`.

Follow this link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-mzdwkd

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
})

export class AppComponent  {

  description = '<p><strong>Test</strong></p><p><span style="background-color: #ed7e32;">Test2</span></p>';

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

   transformYourHtml(htmlTextWithStyle) {
       return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlTextWithStyle);
   }
  }
```

HTML:

`<p [innerHTML]="transformYourHtml(description)"></p>`

Comment: Tried this, but still does not work...really I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: @RobNone Hi Sorry, i understood that you are not using any framework. I thought you are using pure `innerHTML` tag. However, you are using framework `[innerHTML]` directive and which checks content before putting into `dom` for security checks. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are using same quotation marks (") inside and outside of string.
That might cause the problem. Use different ones. Maybe something like this:

```
"<p><strong>Test</strong></p><p><strong><span style='background-color: #ed7e32;'>Test2</span></strong></p>"
```